# PHP is not working with Apache on Lamp server

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I have lamp server on ubuntu, The apache2 is successfully installed and local host is working. But I have no way to create/copy to the www folder, also my phpmyadmin is not working.

Comment: I seem to remember having to have the symbol `^` somewhere during that particular installation?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` (has been asked before so this will probably be closed ;) ) "But nothing to create/copy to www folder is not allowed" has NOTHING to do with installation; you need to set permissions (is a post-install config)

Comment: yes @Tim the ^ tells apt-get to install a "task" and not a package :)

Comment: @Rinzwind seem to have the same idea - look at the newest questions :p. Lots of learning happening here!

Answer (score 1):

easiest would be to

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

then

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

or you could do

```
sudo tasksel
```

and follow the onscreen menu.

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel

Comment: No need for tasksel; as stated in comments add a carrot to "lamp-server" and it will install the task. But that is not the problem he wants solved (the title is misleading) ;)

Comment: yes the title is way of the mark. had to reread twice.

Comment: Ah the new edit is better. Adding the user to the apache access group, or chmod 777 the folder would solve the access issue but there may be a better way you would prefer?

Comment: the correct method is to change files to the user and group apache is set to. Can be `www-data` or `apache`. Should be general knowledge explained on ANY faq or website related to apache and the -minumum- knowledge anyone has to know about webservers (how else are you suppose to keep a system secure? with magic?!)

Comment: on a standard install in Ubuntu, the www folder will already be accessible by apache. the question he faces I believe is that he can not copy files into that folder as himself. as this folder is outside the home folder. he needs to give himself access.

Answer (score 1):

if it shows you a php code in the phpmyadmin may The php is not installed yet 
 the installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

or the php isn't included in the apache 
 you can include it by

```
$ gksu 'gedit etc/apache/apache2.conf'
```

add this line

```
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

& you can copy & edit by opening folder as root

```
$ sudo nautilus '/var/www'
```